How do I physically pass a USB device to a QEMU VM
I've been trying to use a Linux QEMU virtual machine for USB driver development. I wanted to use USB passthrough but when I check the USB device in the VM, it shows some kind of generated product id and vendor id.
Also when I physically plug it in or unplug it, it doesn't respond in the VM.
How do I get it to fully work like it's physically plugged into the VM?

Please show us what you've tried so far. How did you configure usb passthrough?

tried all kinds of things, including vfio-pci, "-device usb-redir", "-device usb-host", also tried spicevmc. all of these ended with the same result

lsusb always shows Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub, Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Most likely qemu isn't run with root and you haven't adapt the permission of the USB device (/dev/bus/usb/xxx/xxx) on the host side.

You need to show how you have configured the VM for this.

Running as root fixed the problem.
